# Best practice for React's setState

Tags: reactjs

With React's relatively new state hook, I was wondering what best practices dictate as far as use cases. For example, which of the two below is preferred:

```
const [water, setWater] = useState('');
```

and then call:

```
if (args._d) {
  setWater(args._d);
}
```

**or:**

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({ water: '' });
```

and then call:

```
if (args._d) {
  setState({ water: 'something' })
}
```

Comment: the first example is preferable as you can declare multiple state variables

Answer (score 1):

Most of the examples I've seen (including the React documentation) use your first approach, especially when dealing with only one piece of state. That said, neither approach is inherently better/worse than the other ([the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables) have some guidance on this).

One thing to note is that the setters returned from `useState` will ***replace, not merge***, the existing state. This becomes important when dealing with multiple state values:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ water: '', food:  []});

// Incorrect! This will overwrite state, removing `food`:
setState({ water: 'H2O' });

// Correct, but more verbose than class-based setState:
setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  water: 'H2O'
}));
```

If you do set multiple values in a single state, the React docs say this:

> we recommend to split state into multiple state variables based on which values tend to change together.

The docs also favor using `useReducer` when state logic becomes more complex. Here's the relevant section in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables